# Get value of md-select from template reference variable, Material for Angular 2

Tags: angular-material, angular2-material

This isn't showing the selected value like it would if it were a textbox instead of a select. What's wrong?

```
<md-select #mySelect>
    <md-option value="1">one</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">two</md-option>
</md-select>
{{ mySelect.value }}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `#variable.selected.value` like this:

```
<md-select #mySelect>
    <md-option value="1">one</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">two</md-option>
</md-select>
<div *ngIf="mySelect.selected">
    {{mySelect.selected.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: And if you're trying to get the selected text, instead of the value, you can use `mySelect.options.item(mySelect.selectedIndex).text`  (maybe off topic, but this answer got me down the right path)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
    <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
    {{food.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
    </md-select>enter code here
    <p> Selected value: {{selectedValue}} </p>
</form>
```

can you try this.

Comment: yes, if you have that `selectedValue` in your class, that works too. but if you want to do `(click)="savePreference(<selected-value-here>)"`, it's cleaner and i think more idiomatic to use a template reference variable.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone using `Angular Material`  Selector `<mat-select>` and looking for a solution to get values inside the template using `#var` you can get values like this

```
<mat-select #mySelect>
    <mat-option value="1">one</mat-option>
    <mat-optionvalue="2">two</mat-option>
</mat-select>
<div *ngIf="mySelect.value">
    {{mySelect.value}} // instead of mySelect.selected.value 
</div>
```

you can use also the same inside `mat-select` loop